# Should NullPointerExceptions be avoided in Integration Tests?

Tags: java, integration-tests

While writing Integration tests for spring applications, I tend to come across checks for different Multilevel Data Objects For Eg: 
[image]

```
AssertNotNull("Node 10 is null", getNode1().getNode8().getNode10().getNode7());
```

This assertions works well provided that Objects A -> B -> C are not null, otherwise if any one of these is null, you end up with an NPE.

On a first view a plausible solution seems to all parent nodes sequentially

```
AssertNotNull("Node 1 is null", getNode1());
AssertNotNull("Node 8 is null", getNode1().getNode8());
AssertNotNull("Node 10 is null", getNode1().getNode8().getNode10());
AssertNotNull("Node 7 is null", getNode1().getNode8().getNode10().getNode7());
```

But if I start doing for every node I would end up having a bunch of cluttered up repeated code floating around.

As it is not development code and I would like to see the cause of the failure and not a raw NPE, specially when I have 100 such tests that assert these. What would be the best practice in this case to avoid NPE or not avoid it at all?

Comment: Why do you have 100 tests that test data objects? What are you actually testing? If you're testing that an operation returns correct results, you shouldn't manually be checking things. Rather have a correct response in some form, then compare the returned value to the correct response in some way (such as serializing to JSON or use reflection to compare, etc.).

Comment: You might find the `Optional` class relevant to your future multilevel data objects.

Answer (score 2):

Your integration tests seems to rely on the construction of specific node trees. From that, I surmise that you're testing a piece of logic that creates the appropriate node tree and returns it.

If that's what you're doing, then it's somewhat obvious that you need to test the node tree's structure. The more complex and varied the possible outputs, the more you have to assert.

---

But isn't part of the "node" approach the fact that nodes are **reusable** pieces of logic?

Would that then not mean that a single test should only really dig **one** layer deep, not several layers? Are you bundling several tests in the same method?

This may be business specific. Maybe you are expecting multilevel trees. Maybe this can be simplifed into a level-by-level creation (and test). That's hard to answer without knowing the specific context.

---

**If** (and only if) this multi-level approach is actually warranted:

```
AssertNotNull("Node 1 is null", getNode1());
AssertNotNull("Node 8 is null", getNode1().getNode8());
AssertNotNull("Node 10 is null", getNode1().getNode8().getNode10());
AssertNotNull("Node 7 is null", getNode1().getNode8().getNode10().getNode7());
```

Are you interested in nodes 1, 8 and 10? Or are you merely "going through the motions" to get to node 7?

If the only meaningful question you're answering is "did I receive a node 7?", then there's no point to asserting the other nodes. If any of them are null, that will force the question about node 7 to respond with "no".

It doesn't make sense to execute four different asserts in order to answer a single binary question ("did I receive a node 7?").

---

**Update from posted comment**

This was a comment reply to the other answer.

I have little experience in Java (I'm a C# dev), but from past experiences it is considered acceptable to try/catch a situation like that in order to not fact-check every step of the way.

In oversimplified C# notation:

```
public bool DoesNode7Exist(Node node1)
{
    try
    {
         return n1.getNode8().getNode10().getNode7() != null; 
    }
    catch
    {
         //catches every possible null in the hierarchy
         return false;
    }
}
```

Note that this is heavily simplified for the sake of example. Also, since C# now has the `?.` operator, this approach has become obsolete; but I'm not sure if Java has a similar solution available nowadays.

---

**Update from your comment**

> This question is in fact use case independant, I dont think its useful to explain the whole business model behind these assertions, Question is simple enough, i wouldn't complicate it further.

As the model is presented in this question, drilling down into the node tree is violating the intended testing methodology. Every level of the tree should be tested individually, which inherently excludes encountering an issue where you drill down more than a single level.

The issue here is that you're bundling several different tests into a single testing method; and then trying to avoid performing every test. It doesn't work like that. You need to test it all, and it needs to be tested in separate steps.

Furthermore, node-based trees inherently rely on **reusable** logic. You only need to test a single node (and its connection to its children) in order to confirm that nodes can be chained indefinitely. This is an additional reason that argues there is no need for drilling down two or more levels, as everything can be tested by observing a single child/parent relationship.

Comment: No support for Elvis in Java. However I don't even see it as a solution, since if you're chaining getters like that you've already taken a wrong turn somewhere. Is this the result of an anemic domain model? Is the test really written correctly (testing for the existence of seemingly arbitrary nodes in an object graph)? And as said, the test will fail anyway, just not to an assert but an exception easily pinpointed to what was null.

Comment: @Kayaman: Which is why I addressed that before digging into the "but what if it is warranted" explanation. I'll update the answer to more explicitly point that out.

Comment: True, true, you did have disclaimers. There's an unfortunately small amount of context for this question.

Comment: The context is clear like crystals or in other words the nodes mentioned in the picture :) Downvoting wouldn't get you anywhere.

Comment: @Anirudh you don't really get to be the judge of that, since you were responsible for providing it. I'm trying to understand whether you're asking the right question or not. I've written plenty of integration tests that check object graphs as well, but I would never encounter a problem like you describe. You shouldn't be getting `NullPointerExceptions` anywhere when performing normal operations. Not in regular code and not in testing code, but the solution to that is hardly "Just ignore nulls", which seems to be what you're after.

Comment: @Anirudh: "unclear" and "arbitrary" are not the same thing. Your current hierarchy is clear from the graph, but the reason for its existence (and usage) is not. The example is too generalized to agree with the approach. There _might_ be a use case here, but we can't find it based on the overgeneralized context. The way the question is currently presented, no test should dig down into more than one level of nodes, thus precluding the issue that your question is based on.

Comment: This question is in fact use case independant, I dont think its useful to explain the whole business model behind these assertions, Question is simple enough, i wouldn't complicate it further.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I suppose it depends.  Are you testing to see if a particular node is null?  Is that part of the test?  Because if it isn't, you shouldn't test for it.  It will fail first time you assume the node isn't null and it is.

So what if you expect a node to possibly be null?  You would test for it like you would in any program and act accordingly:

```
if(getNode1() != null) {
    // Test Node1 ...
}
```

As a general rule, I would say no, you shouldn't be asserting that a node is not null.  Exception to this rule is only when this is the part you're testing:

```
@Test
public void testNode8Existence() {
    AssertNotNull(getNode1().getNode8());
}
```

Comment: Well checking for null or not is a presumption here, problem is when you  assert for a null  for a node in a getter chain call  if one of the parent nodes is null, it would result in NPE before the assertion could spit out the result.

Comment: @Anirudh: I have little experience in Java (I'm a C# dev), but from past experiences it is considered acceptable to try/catch a situation like that in order to not fact-check every step of the way. In oversimplified C# notation `try { return n1.n8.n10.n.7 != null; } catch() { return false; }`. C# now has the `?.` operator, making this approach obsolete; but I'm not sure if Java has a similar solution available nowadays.

Comment: @Anirudh: Any half-decent testing framework should mark a test as failed when an unexpected exception occurs (including NPE), without crashing the test framework. The failure message might not be as specific as you like for an unexpected exception, because something went wrong that your test didn't anticipate, but the message should help you (or the developer) in locating where the problem originates from.

Comment: @Flater I guess you are referring Elvis operator, it's also present in Grrovy and Kotlin I guess. I agree with this approach though.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I agree and I think NullPointers can lead you awry, instead they should be gracefully handled at least printing out a relevant error, I wouldnt do a try-catch though. Something like Elvis Operator can do the trick here.

Comment: @Anirudh: AFAIK, the "elvis" operator is `?:` (e.g. `myBool ? "a" : "b"`). I was referring to `?.` (not sure about name), e.g. `var a = foo?.bar?.baz?.Name`. If **any** of the chained objects is null, `a` will be null and no exception will be thrown.

Comment: `AssertNotNull("Name is null", foo?.bar?.baz?.Name);`  looks fine to me.

Comment: @Anirudh: I mean that the testing framework itself should have such a try-catch and then print something like `Testcase <name> failed with unexpected exception <exception>. Backtrace: <traces>`. As author of the testcase, you should not need to worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

NullPointerExceptions are fine as they tell you that some assumption is broken which is what you want to know (and junit nicely reports anyway which is what you may want to look more into).

What you ALSO want to know is which one that broke!

In that case you can just use the standard way:

```
assertNotNull("node8", Objects.requireNonNull(getNode1(), "node 1").getNode8());
```

or just stick with requireNonNull.

Comment: I disagree, NPE are okay in dev code but for testing code I would rather have it point me to the right root cause.

Comment: `@Anirudh the stacktrace points to the root cause` whats the strong disagreement about the NPE then?

Comment: @Anirudh NPEs are programmer errors resulting from bad code. If you have to deal with NPEs on a regular basis, then your codebase needs improvement. The answer to your question is "NullPointerExceptions should be avoided everywhere". And I still don't understand why you're doing things by hand, that seems slow, ineffective and failure-prone.

Comment: @Anirudh This is about detecting problems which for some reason has not been caught earlier in your testing arsenal (which you have, yes?).  You just want to know what broke which is what you put in the message to requireNonNull.  If your code is as bad as you hint every `.` dereference in your integration test should be preceeded by a null check.

Answer (score 1):

Unit test frameworks have at least these 3 states:

- **Success** -- all assertions passed and reached the end of the test method
- **Failure** -- an assertion failed and an assertion failed exception was thrown
- **Error** -- an unanticipated exception was thrown (I say unanticipated because some unit test frameworks let you provide a method attribute to verify an expected exception was thrown)

Some unit test frameworks have the concept of an *assumption*, where if the assumption fails, the test is skipped.  Those are most useful when you are running the same test against a range of values where some tests only apply in certain situations.  That's not really pertinent to this question though.

#### General Principle

You want it to be obvious what you are testing.  That's why there are good guidelines to separate your test into Arrange, Act, and Assert.  In other words, you set up the prerequisites, perform the action you are really testing, then assert that the outcome is as expected.

#### Assert the important stuff

In cases where there is a chain of potentially nullable objects, and there is only one valid combination, then just assert the final form.  If you receive a NullPointerException (Java) or NullReferenceException (C#) or whatever equivalent in your language, that is a test error.

The trade-off is readability vs. specificity.  Adding an assertion for each stage adds noise that can hide what you are actually attempting to assert.  What you gain out of that is that you know exactly where in the chain you have a null.  However, in long chains like you might get in an object tree that might not be really that important.

This approach makes the real test more visible:

```
AssertNotNull("Node 7 is null", getNode1().getNode8().getNode10().getNode7());

// more specific assertions about Node7 where the real test is
```

If you get a null exception then you know something in the chain is missing.  You might have to fire up the debugger to find out exactly which one of the nodes is null, but that doesn't happen often after you get the test working and most IDEs make it easy to debug your tests.

#### Simplifying API

Tests like this can show the weakness or brittleness of your API.  I understand that object trees are a special case, but in general long method chains like your example tend to be brittle.  It can cause your methods to have a lot of preamble code to ensure the data has the full path to whatever object you need.

Anything you can do to shorten the method chain can only improve the reliability of your code.  In other words there are fewer things to go wrong with short object/method chains.

Those questions should be seriously considered along with whatever trade-offs you have for your code.  It might be the long method chain is really the best option, or at least the cost of fixing the API is too much to take on right now.

Comment: `If you get a null exception then you know something in the chain is missing.`  Good luck debugging that on jenkins.

Comment: @Anirudh, Jenkins isn't a debug tool, it's a build tool.  You debug in your IDE like you always do.  Jenkins is a tool that tells you something is wrong.  It's up to you to actually dig a little deeper using the appropriate tools for the job.

Comment: The point is not even the debugging, when you run the E2E tests through a test framework, you dont want to debug the tests, instead get a clue whats wrong with the application ASAP and file a bug, developers and testers have different view here. Which I understand but as a tester I wouldnt want my jenkins to pile up my jenkins console with null pointers.

Comment: also another compelling reason are soft assertion, when you wanna collect errors and not make the test fail, NPE would simply kill the tests and give incomplete reports.

Comment: @Anirudh, If your test framework stops all tests on the first NPE, then that is a problem with your test framework--or the way you are executing them within Jenkins.  I would also hope that by the time developers are done implementing whatever feature is being worked on, they have made all the unit tests pass.  Lastly, I would seriously look at simplifying your API if at all possible so that you don't have long method chains in the first place.  It seems you've already made up your mind what you want your answer to be.  The world is not so black and white.

Comment: I agree the framework need to be adapted and these getter chains simplified. I am totally for it, and as far as the answer is concerned I see Option as the best choice in this direction, because there is not elvis operator in Java.